# Affix NavBar overlaps the body when zooming

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar, affix

Is there any way to prevent the navbar(with bootstrap affix plugin) from overlaping the body as it's shown here ?

[image: Situation wich is OK]

[image: Situation wich is not OK (using a Tab 8")]

Comment: If it's on a touch device: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/12157 -- the answer is no

Comment: okay i'll leave like that :(